# Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup causing problems with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

My project has been working fine until recently, when I ran `sudo composer self-update`. Composer successfully updated but I could no longer migrate (`php artisan migrate`). This is the error I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ThumbsUp/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

I have ran `composer update` and `composer install`, and still this error persists. Why would it not be finding this class after the `self-update`?

Comment: Read
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446883/laravel-4-fatal-error-class-patchwork-utf8-bootup-not-found-in-autoload-php/28271330#28271330

That answer should help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, I ran `composer dump-autoload` or `php composer.phar dump-autoload` depending on your configuration, ran composer update again and it worked.

Comment: I had to reopen my terminal

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer update` fixed it! And I was struggling with this like forever! Big thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue when trying to run composer update and none of the solutions above had worked. It turns out I had 2 require sections in my composer.json which is actually wrong.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "3.2.x",
    "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "2.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
}
```

Combining the two as below solved my issue.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "3.2.x",
    "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
```

If you still have a problem, try deleting the composer.lock and the vendor directory and run

```
mv ~/.composer/cache ~/.composer/cache.bak
```

To clear the composer cache and finally run

```
sudo composer install
```

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

In tracking down this issue, I found it had to do with this in my composer.json:

`"pre-update-cmd": [
  "php artisan clear-compiled"
],`

My theory is that "clear-compiled" can't work because composer hasn't been updated. Deleting this, and then calling `composer update` and then re-adding it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed composer.lock file and then run `composer update`
And it worked.