# Laravel 4: Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in autoload.php

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php, fatal-error

I added **"cviebrock/image-validator": "1.0.*"** to **require section** of **composer.json**. After, I ran **composer update**, I am getting this Fatal error.

:::ERROR:::

```
Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\project\
bootstrap\autoload.php on line 46
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned wi
th an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-
dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [
packagesN]
```

:::END of ERROR:::

:::COMPOSER.JSON Require section:::

```
"require": {
  "intervention/image": "2.*",
  "cviebrock/image-validator": "1.0.*"
},
```

I need help in rectifying this fatal error.

Thanks & Regards,

Michael Sangma

Comment: I got this from github [link] (https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel/issues/30).

The solution they gave is to add 'oauth dependency' to the require section. Now, I don't know the exact line of 'oauth dependency' to add.

Can anyone help me with this? I would like to try this solution found in github.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This error seems to me like there is no `patchwork/utf8` package installed.

See in your vendor folder whether the package exists or add in the require section in your composer.json file: `"patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*"` and then do `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem because when I run 
php artisan db:seed  --class=PostsTableSeeder

it started to remove laravel, symfony etc. I can't understand why?(may be my composer.json included at that time only `"require": {
  "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
},`)

So what I did, I updated my composer.json again and run composer update --dev. composer.json as

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "way/generators": "~2.0",
    "patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
},
```

And that worked because it downloaded again everything.

Comment: I did the same thing and it worked. It downloaded everything again. But, still why does that happen? If every time that happens I have to follow this solution, then the problem still remains.

Comment: @michaelsangma I don't know another solution that's why I also searched on stackoverflow and google. Finally I came to this solution. If you have a better one please post here.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented the 'Patchwork\Utf8\Utf8ServiceProvider' in app.php and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I Solved It With `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer update`

After that it works 
But if you encounter more issue try to
Delete the vendor folder or just rename it fo backup puporse incase it fails like   `mv vendor ve`  then

```
Delete composer.lock
```

Run the command composer clearcache (or clear-cache)
Run composer install

Your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you just have to do this:

```
composer require patchwork/utf8
```

Answer (score -1):

I am most certain you pulled your application from a git? If you take a closer look at your `.gitignore` file you would see that `/vendor` is one of the files/folders that git was told to ignore. You need to remove `/vendor`, `composer.lock` and `composer.phar` from `.gitignore` **IF** you're in development.

Also if you navigate to the `/vendors` folder via FTP or ssh, you will see that it only has folders that were outlined in your composer.json file under

```
"require": {

}
```

are the ones in the vendor folder.

Once you run `composer update` and `composer install` you should be fine.

Comment: You should ***never*** have your vendor folder under git. You should have your composer.json, which takes care of everything.

Comment: @CamilStaps If you are following the discussion it never outlines anything about publishing a project onto git Please read before commenting and down voting.!

Comment: You did mention "remove /vendor, composer.lock and composer.phar from .gitignore". This is a Bad Idea. Take composer.lock for example, it's basically just a saved version of composer.json. If you have the json, you don't need the lock. The phar should never change and is a binary, why have it under git? And vendor should never be changed than by running composer, and the changes are defined by the changes in composer.json - so, again, composer.json is sufficient.

Comment: Seems like english isn't your first language. Like i mentioned before no one is publishing anything to git or any other svn. My answer was a solution to a problem. I meant everything that I said there because it worked. Please read and understand dialogue before input. In your case your input isn't accurate to what is discussed here. I can understand if it was a project being pushed to github and I said to remove `/vendor` from `.gitignore` your down vote would have made sense. In this case your showing ignorance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "git or any other svn", specifically "an svn". You probably mean a VCS (Version Control System). Git, like SVN (Subversion) is a VCS. It doesn't make sense to say Git is an svn. It doesn't matter whether you're using a remote like Github or not, putting /vendor, composer.{lock,phar} under version control (in git, SVN or any other CVS) 1) is pointless, because of the reasons above, 2) is a waste of space in the revision history and 3) clutters the revision history with needless commits and binaries.

Comment: Besides that, what you have in your gitignore has ***no influence*** on what composer update / install does. It does also ***not*** make sense to first run composer update, then install. You run either the first or the second, there's never need for running both. If you don't want to use Git locally for whatever reason, you should remove the .git directory, not the .gitignore. Removing the .git directory removes the complete revision history and makes you unable from running any git commands in that directory. What that has to do with composer? Nothing, nothing at all.

Comment: **This post shows a large misunderstanding of the working of 1) Git and 2) Composer.** Concerning your snarky comment about English not being my first language: 1) it indeed isn't, 2) why is it relevant?, 3) yours isn't English either, 4) mine is better than yours, and 5) again, why does it matter?

Comment: It matters because your missing the point of not understand the question/answer at hand.

Comment: Please see: http://youryoure.com/. Considering you also misunderstood the Git/SVN/Composer manual *big time*, I don't consider your attack on my English of much value. But you're a grown man; you're entitled to your opinion.