# how to run a github pulled project with laravel?

Tags: php, git, laravel, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

i just cloned a project from **bitbucket** with sourcetree. Now i am trying to run it with laravel. I started my cmd with administrator rights and i am in the right directory of the project. Now when i try to do the '**composer update**' command i get this error in my command line :

[image]

i know this topic was been discussed before but i couldn't find the answer in them for me. This must have something to do with the fact that me and my friend are making this laravel project together and we are using source tree with bitbucket as a version control system , he can run the project on his computer but when i pull it , it stopped working. Is there annything i need to keep in in mind when using laravel with git ?

Comment: Try `composer install` instead

Comment: it gets me the same error :/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when i cloned the repository from github.
what id did is

> Composer Install

using the terminal in my app directory. It worked A1!
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use `composer install` because laravel by default exludes the following directories from git:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
.env
```

Which could be causing your error

Another similar question was asked here covering the same error: [Laravel 4: Fatal error: Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446883/laravel-4-fatal-error-class-patchwork-utf8-bootup-not-found-in-autoload-php)

Comment: i just cloned a new repo and did composer install on a fresh cloned project and it gave me the same error :/

Comment: You could try searching for another project on github that uses laravel and see if you still have that same error. Then try composer install on that

Comment: i'm going to my friend and i am going to get the project by usb maybe this will fix some problems , i will post here if that worked