# Could not install laravel-snappy in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Trying to install laravel-snappy via this command:

```
composer require "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.1.x"
```

but getting error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package 0.1.x at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

My composer.json:

```
"config": {
   "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

Also tried with (composer.json)

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

and

```
composer require "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.1.2"
```

and

`composer require "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.1.x"`

Would anyone please tell me what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the package name and version, and add in the @dev stability flag:

```
composer require "barryvdh/laravel-snappy":"0.1.x@dev"
```

The other option is to manually edit your composer.json file to add in the dependency, and then run composer update:

```
composer update "barryvdh/laravel-snappy"
```

Comment: That space between the package name and version has been completely oblivious to me for so long and packages never seemed to install!!! Very frustrating. Thanks so much for your answer @patricus

Answer (score 0):

add this to your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "~5.0",
    "patchwork/utf8": "1.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.2.*@dev"
},
```

if this generates and error then check this:

[Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup causing problems with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151402/patchwork-utf8-bootup-causing-problems-with-laravel-4)